# How does one ‘contract’ strings to escape special characters in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, escaping

There are many ways to *expand* an escaped string, but how can a shell command be made to take a string as an argument and escape it?

Here are some examples of different ways of expansion:

```
$ echo -e '\x27\\012\b34\n56\\\aa7\t8\r 9\0\0134\047'
'\0134
 9\'7   8
$ echo $'\x27\\012\b34\n56\\\aa7\t8\r 9\0\0134\047'
'\0134
 9\a7   8
$ PS1='(5)$ '  # At least tab-width - 3 long; 5 columns given typical tab-width.
(5)$ printf %b '\x27\\012\b34\n56\\\aa7\t8\r 9\0\0134\047'
'\0134
 9\'(5)$
```

*Note: there's actually a tab character between the 7 and 8 above, but the markup rendering seems to break it.*

Yes, all sorts of craziness in there. ;-)

Anyway, I'm looking for the reverse of such escape expansion commands. If the command was called `escape`, it would satisfy these properties:

```
$ echo -ne "$(escape "$originalString")"
```

*Should output the verbatim value of `originalString` as would ‘`echo -n "$originalString"`’. I.e. it should be an identity.*

Likewise:

```
$ escape "$(echo -ne "$escapedString")"
```

*Should output the string escaped again, though not necessarily in the same way as before. E.g. `\0134` may become `\\` or vice versa.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `echo -e` -- it's very poorly specified in POSIX, and considered deprecated for all but the simplest uses. Bash has extensions to its `printf` that provide a better-supported approach:

```
printf -v escaped_string %q "$raw_string"
```

...gives you a shell-escaped string from a raw one (storing it in a variable named `escaped_string`), and

```
printf -v raw_string %b "$escaped_string"
```

...gives you a raw string from a backslash-escaped one, storing it in `raw_string`.

---

Note that the two escape syntaxes are not equivalent -- strings escaped with `printf %q` are ready for `eval`, rather than for `printf %b`.

That is, you can safely run:

```
eval "myvar=$escaped_string"
```

...when `escaped_string` has been created with `printf %q` as above.

---

That said: What's the use case? It's strongly preferred to handle raw strings *as raw strings* (using NUL terminaters when delimiting is necessary), rather than converting them to and from an escaped form.

Comment: Thank you! I had looked in the `printf` manpage but unfortunately it doesn't even mention `%q`. Bash's manpage mentions it under _SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS_; the `printf` manpage is GNU Coreutils which unfortunately don't care for manpages. Thanks for pointing out the `echo -e` deprecation; from now on I'll try to get into the habit of using `printf` instead of `echo`.

Comment: I'm actually asking because I don't want to use `NUL` as a delimiter because the raw strings may have any character in them, but using `eval` is absolutely not an option if it's the escaped strings that cross a privilege boundary. Is there really no direct inverse of `printf %b`, or an inverse of `printf %q` that doesn't rely on escaped input to be safe?

Comment: @JamesHaigh, when you say "any" character, you mean including NUL? You can't store NULs in standard bash scalar variables, so I don't know how you'd expect an unescaping function or method that could handle data containing NULs to work unless it wrote into an array rather than a string.

Comment: ...so, f'rinstance, if you're representing your NUL-containing byte string in an arary (with each NUL as an element boundary), then serializing/deserializing it is easy: Write the array length, then the NUL-delimited values, and you're done; reading is the exact inverse, and no privilege issues to deal with.

Comment: ...and if you want details on how to do that, and there isn't already an answer on-point, feel free to write it up as a separate question and point me to it. :)

Comment: Put another way, `eval "echo -n $(printf %q "$originalString")"` does seem to be a perfect identity, but `printf %q "$(eval "echo -n $escapedString")"` is unsafe if `escapedString` is not correctly escaped.

Comment: Sorry, just seen your new comments. Okay, thanks, I didn't realise that Bash itself can't handle `NUL`s. I'll look into your suggestion, thanks. :-)

Comment: @JamesHaigh, *nod*. bash uses C strings everywhere, so they're all innately NUL-delimited; that's why `s=$'foo\0bar'; echo ${#s}` returns `3`, not `7`.